# Three.js : Scenes not appearing in Safari Mac

Tags: javascript, three.js, safari

I'm developing website with multiple scene(canvas) on page. everything in working fine in Chrome. safari(Mobile), but it's not working in Safari mac.

I'm using https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-multiple-scenes.html this article's technique of

> render to an off screen canvas and copy the result to a 2D canvas at
> each element

```
            camera.aspect = rect.width / rect.height;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uttam_1137/j5yuLs4t/75/

As you can see in above JSFiddle, it's working perfectly fine in Safari without any resizing issue. And I'm using same concept in my website but in Safari this issue occurs.

**UPDATE:**
I tried on different safari on different mac and find out it works. but still there is small catch, I've to adjust size of browser before seen appears on scree.

link : [PulsAero Agency](https://pulsaero.agency/)

can anyone tell what's the problem could be.

**Solution**

Finally I figured it out. using `max-width` and giving `50%` width to the scene, was causing the problem.
because of it in safari width was not whole number. So what i did is below

```
rect.width = Math.round(rect.width);
```

added above code in `animate` function.

working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/uttam_1137/j5yuLs4t/76/

Comment: I can reproduce with Safari on my iMac. Do you mind trying to isolate the issue with a [small live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)? Right now, it is difficult to investigate the problem because the app includes many different resource. Besides, the JavaScript app code in `index.html` is obfuscated/minimized which makes it impossible to debug the app.

Comment: Looking from W10 Firefox and Chrome, the multi example JSFiddle above isn't rendering the cubes, but the Agency link is working from load. If you're having to adjust the screen first it usually points to the camera.aspect not setting initially (as long as render is called.) Can you "trace log" through your live version and check all is loading properly? Then debug the camera angles (more difficult to pin down.)

Comment: @Mugen87 i've added JSFiddle, please help me out.

Comment: The fiddle and the website works with Chrome and Firefox on macOS. With Safari, the website shows the issue but interestingly the fiddle works as expected! So there must be an additional feature at the website which breaks the rendering.

Comment: @Mugen87 i've updated the fiddle. now it's producing the exact issue as my website.

Comment: I don't know why but it seems the usage of the `max-width` CSS property breaks Safari. If I remove it, it works on my machine https://jsfiddle.net/njtgs3mf/

Comment: yes @Mugen87  `max-width` was was causing the issue. Finally solved it. Thank you.